# Sitecore publishing using the "Change Restrictions" options is stuck using UTC time

Tags: .net, sitecore

We have a production system which has one Content Management System and two Content Delivery Systems setup according to the Scaling Guide.

We've recently had a need to set content to expire and have been using the "Change Restrictions" feature in the Content Authoring view to set the schedule for when the content expires.   This works, however,  the expiration time always happens from the UTC timezone.

What is my best option to make that happen in Eastern Daylight Time?    Both CM and CDs are were set to EDT and I've since moved them to UTC to try and counter the issue with no affect.

Thanks!

Comment: And what about database servers? did you set timezone on it to be EDT?

Comment: Thanks for the response.   I'm pretty sure your on to something because these sites are running using Amazon Web Services RDS and there is actually not an ability to change the timezone. (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=161339)   The only thing currently affected is this publishing feature and we might have to add a customization to due the timezone conversion.

Comment: In Sitecore document page 8 http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/scaling_guide_sc63-64-a4.pdf
It says you need to synchronize time on servers (web and databases)
So, its a good shoot to try setting the time zone on environment to be the same